# Jenkins if condition does not work as expected

Tags: if-statement, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my Jenkins pipleline code. When I supply either Build/Test/Deploy as a choice, it should print the echo line but it does not.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have attached the output below for your reference.

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    parameters{
        string(name: 'my_string', defaultValue: 'Bharath', description: 'Give a name to print')
        booleanParam(name: 'T_or_F', defaultValue: true, description: 'Either True or False')
        choice(name: 'my_choice', choices: 'Build\nTest\nDeploy\n', description: 'my own choice')
    }

    stages{

        stage('Tools'){
            steps{
                echo 'my_string: $my_string or ${params.my_string} (both are same)'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Choose'){
            steps{
                script{
                    if(params.T_or_F){
                        echo 'The value of boolean is set to True'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Test'){
            steps{
                script{
                    if(params.choice=='Test'){
                        echo 'Test section will execute.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                script{
                    if(params.choice=='Build'){
                        echo 'Build section will execute.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Deploy'){
            steps{
                script{
                    if(params.choice=='Deploy'){
                        echo 'Deploy section will execute.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I am expecting that the echo of one of Build/Test/Deploy should print in the output, but it does not. Please see below.

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on remotebuildnode in /home/demouser/data/workspace/params-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Tools)
[Pipeline] echo
my_string: $my_string or ${params.my_string} (both are same)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Choose)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
The value of boolean is set to True
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: You use param.choice but the name of the param is my_choice.